# Mounting OneDrive without Microsoft Account

Tags: mount, online-storage, rclone

I am trying to mount a OneDrive so that we can easily back up data files to a cloud server. Our databank is somewhat large (10TB) so we wanted to store it on our lab's OneDrive.

I followed the OneDrive RClone mounting tutorial described in these forums on my personal laptop, and was able to mount OneDrive without issue. However, our study team OneDrive is not linked to a microsoft account. As far as we can tell it is a OneDrive created by the University which the study team has been given access to, and our tech support has told us there is no microsoft account associated with it.

Is there a way to mount a OneDrive without using microsoft account credentials? Our tech support suggested creating a shortcut to the study OneDrive in our personal OneDrive, but the shortcut does not appear on a mounted personal drive.

Comment: This seems to be a question to ask Microsoft support and in any case has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: are you not able to use Settings > Online Accounts > Microsoft and sign in to your account or with the GitHub option in Ubuntu?